# join query on contacts content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

How can we run join query on content provider?
I need to query Contacts.CONTENT_URI for all rows where account_type = "custom.account.type".
but account_type column is not available in Contacts.CONTENT_URI. Account_type column is available in Rawcontacts.CONTENT_URI.

One thing i can do is get contactsIDs from Rawcontacts.CONTENT_URI where account_type = "custom.account.type". and than query Contacts.CONTENT_URI.
is there any better option for this?